# Require in global scope or local scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope

What is the correct way to require a node module? Is it more accurate/understandable to declare the module in the global scope, or is it more accurate/understandable to declare the module in the local scope?

For example, which of these makes the most sense:

Global:

```
let dns = require('dns') // <-- Global scope declaration
function lookup(subdomain, domain){
    let fqdn
    if(subdomain == '@'){
        fqdn = domain
    } else {
        fqdn = `${subdomain}.${domain}`
    }
    dns.resolveTxt(fqdn, (err, records) => {
        if(records){
            console.log(records)
        } else {
            console.log("no recrods")
        }
    })
}
```

Local:

```
function lookup(subdomain, domain){
    let dns = require('dns') // <-- Local scope declaration
    let fqdn
    if(subdomain == '@'){
        fqdn = domain
    } else {
        fqdn = `${subdomain}.${domain}`
    }
    dns.resolveTxt(fqdn, (err, records) => {
        if(records){
            console.log(records)
        } else {
            console.log("no recrods")
        }
    })
}
```

Is it a matter of opinion? If so, my apologies and I will delete the question.

I am looking to improve my code so others can more easily understand it, and I think this question is relevant to that purpose, so it shouldn't be considered an opinionated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a minor correction.  Your first example is not global scope.  That's module scope.  Module scope with the declaration located at the beginning of your module file is the preferred implementation for the following reasons:

1. It loads at startup (see text below for why that's good).
2. Locating all these at the beginning of your module file clearly states in the code what external module dependencies you have in a nice easy to see way which is useful for anyone coming back to this code in the future to do maintenance (including you).
3. You only ever `require()` this module once in this module.  While modules are cached, it's better to not be calling `require()` every time you want to reference it.  Load it once and use that saved module reference.

About point 1 above, `require()` is blocking and synchronous and involves accessing the file system (the first time that file is loaded).  You generally want to get all your `require()` operations done at server-startup so no blocking operations are happening while you are processing requests.  And, if you get any errors from `require()` (such as a module install missing or version conflict or bad configuration or missing dependency or something like that), you also want those to happen at startup time, not later where they are quicker to see and easier to diagnose.

Comment: One point of confusion for me in your first paragraph: If I'm writing a javascript file that will be run using `node.js`: e.g. `$> node myFile.js` that does not have `module exports`, is that still a module? I'm looking at `local` vs `global` scope from the perspective of the js file... Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Dshiz - Yes, it is still a module. If you were to declare this variable at the top level and then load some other module, your variable would only be available in this file, it would not be available globally to other modules.  Each commonjs code file you use in nodejs, whether it's the main one loaded from the command line or one loaded via `require()` all get their code wrapped into a [module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) which makes all top level declarations be only in module scope.  See that link for details.

Comment: Thank you.. You're quite ubiquitous on this site; I always appreciate your answers on my questions and on others...

Comment: @Dshiz - Yeah, I should probably be working on other things, but I enjoy answering questions here.  Glad to help.